# wtf form change style on file input

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I am using wtf forms with flask to create a form.
I have a file input, which is styled so the default button is not shown.
How can I dynamically change the style after a file is loaded?

Here is my code:

html:

```
 <div class="file-upload my-form">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/dy62M.png" />
        {{ wtf.form_field(form.file)}}
    </div>
```

css:

```
.my-form input {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}
.file-upload {
  margin: 40px auto;
  border: 1px solid #149174;
  border-radius: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.file-upload input {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 600px;
  left: 10px;
  top: 20px;
}

.file-upload img {
  height: 170px;
  width: 170px;
  margin: 60px;
}
```

how can I change the style on input? or show a label with the file name in the worst case...[image: This is what the input looks like now]

Comment: take a look here https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/fields/#wtforms.fields.Field.__call__, you could possibly add an additional attribute `style` or add an id or class.

Comment: Can you add the code from your backend api for your form  object and your entire html file and what it renders to when it serves it to the user?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I dealt with it like this:

```
function fileCheck() {
    var checked = document.getElementById('file')
    if (checked.value.length > 0) {
        var file_name = checked.value.split(/(\\|\/)/g).pop();
        var re = /(?:\.([^.]+))?$/;
        var ext = re.exec(file_name)[1];
        if (ext != 'pdf') {
            document.getElementById('file-container').style.backgroundColor = '#ca2c2c';
            document.getElementById("file-desc").innerHTML = "File Loaded with illegal extension: " + ext + " !!";
            document.getElementById("final-submit").disabled = true;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('file-container').style.backgroundColor = '#149174';
            document.getElementById("file-desc").innerHTML = "File Loaded: " + checked.value.split(/(\\|\/)/g).pop();
            document.getElementById("final-submit").disabled = false;
        }
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("final-submit").disabled = true;
    }

}
```

And my html looks like this:

```
<div class="file-upload my-form" id="file-container">
                <img src="static/images/upload_icon.png" />
                {{ form.file(oninput="fileCheck()") }}
            </div>
```